# In Renjin, trying to write R script without losing the quotations

Tags: java, r, renjin

Let's say that I have the following Java code, using Renjin to run R on the JVM:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
// create a Renjin engine:
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("Renjin");
```

I want to evaluate the following R code using Renjin:

```
analysis.time<-format(Sys.time(), "%a %b %d %X %Y")
```

To do this, I have this Java Code using Renjin:

```
engine.eval("analysis.time<-format(Sys.time(), "%a %b %d %X %Y")");
```

However, because of the quotes around `%a %b %d %X %Y` , my code is broken up in two parts. How can I write this to keep it consistent?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an escape character (a backslash (`\`)) in front of the quotes that are part of `"%a %b %d %X %Y`".